so i am following solana bootcamp and getting this error bigint
i am using nextjs with typescript  https://www.soldev.app/course/interact-with-wallets#content
and following this lab but when i am doing npm run dev i am getting this error
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/useConnection.js:8:79)
at (rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/useConnection.js (C:\Users\singh\Desktop\solana\solana-ping-frontend.next\server\vendor-chunks@solana.js:348:1)
at webpack_require (C:\Users\singh\Desktop\solana\solana-ping-frontend.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-react/lib/esm/ConnectionProvider.js:7:75)

Node is trying to load a native dependency (i think its in c++) to load the bigint which you dont seem to have installed and instead reverts to using pureJs. I get the same error but it's not a problem, just a bit slower.

i just forgot to make it a client component and then installed pino-pretty as a dependency , and the issue solved for me
